# Override target framework from command line

Tags: c#, msbuild

I want to build a `c#` project(.csproj) from commandline using `msbuild` and want to target .Net2.0 runtime.

I see that the project xml file has `2 tags` of interest

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" ...
```

and

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

I was wondering if

- Can ToolsVersion 4.0 produce compatible code for .Net2.0 runtime?
- Can I override the target framework tag from the project file via the command line (does the `/ToolsVersion` command line switch achieve this?

I specifically want to achieve this via command line and not modify the project file.

Currently I am doing something like this

```
msbuild myproj.csproj /p:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need the commandline arguments for msbuild to make that work:

```
msbuild.exe MyProj.proj /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v2.0;Configuration=Release /tv:3.5
```

therfore overriding the value in the proj file aswell as the ToolsVersion.

To find out which msbuild version default is used, start a Visual Studio Command prompt ( found in the Start menu > Microsoft Visual studio 2010 > Visual Studio Tools) and type msbuild.
The first line of the output will hold your BuidEngineversion:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1

From the msdn doc:

> MSBuild uses a tool set of tasks, targets, and tools to build an
>   application. Typically, a MSBuild tool set includes a
>   microsoft.common.tasks file, a microsoft.common.targets file, and
>   compilers such as csc.exe and vbc.exe. Most tool sets can be used to
>   compile applications to more than one version of the .NET Framework
>   and more than one system platform

You could also check the Environment vars for a version of the framework installed:
`set F` from the Visual Studio Command prompt gives me this result:

> Framework35Version=v3.5
>   FrameworkDir=c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
>   FrameworkDIR32=c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
>   FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
>   FrameworkVersion32=v4.0.30319

[ToolSet Explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397428)
[ToolSetVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796)

Comment: If toolsversion is set to 4.0 would the resulting assembly run on v2.0 runtime??

Comment: Yes it will, tv only indicates which tools (targets/compilers etc) msbuild used to produce the assembly for the requested framework

Comment: I see that I have multiple msbuild.exe one each in the folders v2.0, v3.0 and v4.0 which one is best to use

Comment: I would not bother, use the one that runs default. I expect it always to be the one from highest installed toolset. So if you have 4.0 installed it will use the 4.0 msbuild.

Comment: I cannot run msbuild from any other path unless I run it from the framework directory itself is there any other way to check the default msbuild version