# Multiple framework publishing issue

Tags: c#

I have a Window Form project targeting Framework 4.6.1.
This project is referencing a project that targets multiple framework.

When I'm doing the publishing using msBuild /t:Publish I get the error

The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework. The current project targets multiple frameworks, please specify the framework for the published application.

My question is the following how to I specify a target framework. Since my solution startup project is only targeting 4.6.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override target framework from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003475/override-target-framework-from-command-line)

Comment: @Amy This is now exactly the same thing as I'm not building a Project but a solution.

When using the TargetFrameworkVersion argument. I get the following error message MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.

Comment: Just build the project you want to publish.  msbuild will include the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to choose one of the target frameworks in the referenced project and specify that as a msbuild property.  Something like:

```
msbuild -property:TargetFramework=net6.0 -target:publish
```

Comment: Thank for taking the time to answer. 
I'll accept your answer even though I cannot test it as its been quite some time.

Comment: @JM123 I figured you have probably moved on from this question, as it is a while ago.  So, I'm mainly posting, so that this might be helpful to someone else coming to this question in the future.  In any case, thanks!